# How to enable and disable Parse push notifications Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have an Android app which is integrated with Parse services to be able to receive push notification, all is working fine, but I want to add a switch that lets the users enable or disable receiving push notifications on their device, but I couldn't find the right way to do it. Any help would be much appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to achieve this to add a boolean field lets say "enable" to your ParseInstallation object for each app installation. You can update the ParseInstallation for the user each time the update switch is toggle on/off.
Just make sure you check for the "enable" field before pushing any notification.

Comment: how can I update the parse installation to not receive push notificiations for this device?

Comment: this does not let the device receive push notifications? this is the default installation, please can you provide clear code about this, it would be much appreciated with an upvote and an accepted answer thanks.

Comment: You should provide some code sample related to your answer, only theory is not sufficient for accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

```
ParseInstallation currentInst = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation(); 
currentInst.put("enable", "<true/false>"); 
currentInst.saveInBackground();
```

Now, before pushing a notification, query your installation like this

```
ParsePush parsePush = new ParsePush(); 
ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> installationParseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseInstallation.class); 
installationParseQuery.whereEqualTo("enable", true); 
parsePush.sendInBackground();
```

Comment: Oh I guess you understood me wrong, I want to enable and disable the receive operation not the send operation, can you please edit your code to achieve this? thanks.

Comment: I think i understand you. By setting the custom enable field to false. The users wouldn't get any push notification. All you just need do is make sure you query this field before pushing from your app or cloud code

Comment: I am pushing from Parse server, how can I do this query before pushing?

Comment: If you are sending from the Parse website, you just need to add a parse installation condition where "enable" equals "true".